# PowerDesigner (Database design) - add PK to cross-reference table

Tags: database-design, sybase, case, powerdesigner, conceptual-model

i would like to know how to add PK to cross - reference table which is created from converting  Conceptual Model to Physical Model and associate it with other table as FK.

**Conceptual Model**

[image: Conceptual Model]

**Physical Model**

[image: Physical Model]

**Expected Result**

Physical Model

- Job Applications Table : PK ja_id(int)
- Applications Table : FK ja_id(int)

I think i've described my problem clear enough :)

Thanks for help !

Comment: I guess the answer you propose is the logical consequence of your description: first you said "Job Applications" is an association; but then you added "... but it has an identity, other than the couple of extremities of the association".

Comment: That's an awful lot of ID numbers for a conceptual model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround for my question is shown in attached pics.

**Conceptual Model**

[image: Conceptual Model]

** Physical Model**

[image: Physical Model]